# loop through an array of request data and save per set to the database laravel

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have this var_dump result

```
'children' => 
    array (size=2)
        0 => string 'children on row 1' (length=17)
        1 => string 'children on row 2' (length=17)
'type_of_delivery' => 
    array (size=2)
        0 => string 'type of delivery on row 1' (length=25)
        1 => string 'type of delivery on row 2' (length=25)
'date' => 
    array (size=2)
        0 => string 'Oct 11, 2015' (length=12)
        1 => string 'Oct 11, 2015' (length=12)
```

from my inputs

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Children</th>
            <th>Type of Delivery</th>
            <th>Date</th>
        <tr>
    <thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="children[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="type_of_delivery[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="date[]" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="children[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="type_of_delivery[]" /></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="date[]" /></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I have a columns 'children', 'type_of_delivery', 'date' for those request data. I want to save it like per set e.g. array 0 of children + array 0 of type_of_delivery + array 0 date and so on.

Assume I have successfully save those data and it should look like this.

```
--------------------------------------------------------------
     children     |    type of delivery       |  date
--------------------------------------------------------------
children on row 1 | type of delivery on row 1 | Oct 11, 2015
children on row 2 | type of delivery on row 2 | Oct 11, 2015
```

any ideas, clues, help how to make it please?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Answer (score -1):

Providing your array stays in the same format, you could do the following: -

```
$children = $arr['children'];

for (i=0; i < count($children); i++)
{
    $update = [
        'children' => $children[$i],
        'type_of_delivery' => $arr['type_of_delivery'][$i], 
        'date' => $arr['date'][$i],  
    ];

    Your\Model\To\Insert::create($update);
}
```

This will only work if you have equal results across `children`, `delivery` & `date`

Comment: I dont quite get this. Can you explain a little about your code above please?